# How to plot a real time signal in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, video, plot

I'm building a smile detection system, and I need to plot the probability of smile (from video input) like the graphs on the right in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-53aku3axo).

How can I do this in MATLAB?

### Notes

I'm currently displaying the video frames with OpenCV & IntraFace default code, which looks something like this :

```
cf = 0; % Current Frame.
% create a figure to draw upon
S.fh = figure('units','pixels',...
              'position',[100 150 frame_w frame_h],...
              'menubar','none',...
              'name','Smile Detector',...              
              'numbertitle','off',...
              'resize','off',...
              'renderer','painters');

% create axes
S.ax = axes('units','pixels',...  
            'position',[1 1 frame_w frame_h],...
            'drawmode','fast');

set(S.fh,'KeyPressFcn',@pb_kpf);          

S.im_h = imshow(zeros(frame_h,frame_w,3,'uint8'));
hold on;
S.frame_h = text(50,frame_h-50,['Frame ' int2str(cf)] , 'fontsize', 15, 'Color' , 'c');

while true && ~stop_pressed
  tic;
  im = cap.read;  
  cf = cf + 1;        
  if isempty(im), 
    warning('EOF'); 
    break ;
  end

  set(S.im_h,'cdata',im); % update frame
  set(S.frame_h , 'string' ,['Frame ' int2str(cf)]);  
  do_something_with_frame(im);

  if isempty(output.pred) % if lost/no face, delete all drawings      
    if drawed, delete_handlers(); end
  else % face found       
    update_GUI(); 
  end
drawnow;
end

close;

end
```

And I want to add a live / moving graph like in the video. The graph will display a single value (a probability) between 0 and 1. And it should be updated with every new frame, therefore the plot should "flow" as the video flows.

### What Have I Tried

I tried creating a new figure just like `S` in the code. But I cannot plot into it. I am also ok with adding the live graph in the same figure (`S.fh`), preferrably under the scene.

Comment: Normaly, just by calling a figure with name or number, you can redraw on with. So like `figure(1); hold on; plot(x,y,'o'); imshow(Img); hold off;`. And by calling this line in a loop with (x,y) changing, your point will be added.

Comment: Sorry, don't need imshow(Img) in your case, I copy-paste what I do sorry. But your plot will be under the image in that case or if point are outside image boundary, they will be display. So If you use GUI, just take the axis you create and update plot.

Answer (score 1):

Using linkdata and refreshdata will refresh a graph plot as you have new data.

```
    %some pretend data
    pX1 = rand;
    pX2 = 1-pX1;
    p = [pX1,pX2];
    bar(p)

    %link the data to the plot
    linkdata on

    for i=1:100
       pX1 = rand;
       pX2 = 1-pX1;
       p = [pX1,pX2];
       %refresh the linked data and draw
       refreshdata
       drawnow
    end
```

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/linkdata.html

Hope it helps...